# How to dynamically render a tree of data in svelte?

Tags: javascript, electron, svelte

I have a tree of data that i'm using to represent a directory of the file system. It look something like this.

```
    {
        isRoot: true
        path: "/path/to/dir"
        fileName: "dir",
        isDirectory: true,
        parent: null,
        children: [
            {
                isRoot: false
                path: "/path/to/dir/file1.txt"
                fileName: "file1.txt",
                isDirectory: true,
                parent: {...spread parent node here},
                children: null
            },
            {
                isRoot: false
                path: "/path/to/dir/subdir"
                fileName: "subdir",
                isDirectory: true,
                parent: {...spread parent node here},
                children: [
                    {
                        isRoot: false
                        path: "/path/to/dir/subdir/file2.txt"
                        fileName: "file2.txt",
                        isDirectory: false,
                        parent: {...spread parent node here},
                        children: null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to take each node and turn it into this.

```
<Node branch={some parent from that tree} >
    <Node branch={a child of that parent} />
    <Node branch={another child of that parent>
        <Node branch={a child of the new parent />
    </Node>
</Node
```

I know that svelte allows you to loop through arrays and render content based on each item however there is no way of knowing what the tree looks like.

**Is there any way to dynamically render this tree in svelte?**

Comment: Dynamic folder in the examples: https://svelte.dev/examples#svelte-self and click te folders

Comment: Is there a way to implement the folders example in JavaScript only, without using the template language. Being limited to each and if is problematic for for highly dynamic content, such as building complex tables.

Comment: The solution is probably to use recursive components with `<svelte:self>`. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self

Answer (score 1):

This unanswered question came up in a search two years after being asked, so I'll go ahead and answer it while I'm here. The comments on the question just needed to be filled out to become a proper answer.

As the comments to your question have already explained, you'll need to use the recursive `<svelte:self>` component. It represents the component that is being defined in that particular module. In other words, if you are defining a `<Folder>` component and want to have other folders inside it, you would refer to them as `<svelte:self>` inside the definition of `<Folder>`. This is because a module cannot import itself.

The Svelte Tutorial has a [specific module](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self) on this exact scenario, so everyone who writes code in Svelte should go through the [entire tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics) (it's not long) and learn the basics of Svelte. You would want to do something quite similar to the example.

Here is the example shown in the tutorial:

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
import Folder from './Folder.svelte';

let root = [
    {
        name: 'Important work stuff',
        files: [
            { name: 'quarterly-results.xlsx' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Animal GIFs',
        files: [
            {
                name: 'Dogs',
                files: [
                    { name: 'treadmill.gif' },
                    { name: 'rope-jumping.gif' }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'Goats',
                files: [
                    { name: 'parkour.gif' },
                    { name: 'rampage.gif' }
                ]
            },
            { name: 'cat-roomba.gif' },
            { name: 'duck-shuffle.gif' },
            { name: 'monkey-on-a-pig.gif' }
        ]
    },
    { name: 'TODO.md' }
];
</script>

<Folder name="Home" files={root} expanded/>
```

`File.svelte`

```
<script>
export let name;
$: type = name.slice(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
</script>

<span style="background-image: url(/tutorial/icons/{type}.svg)">{name}</span>

<style>
    span {
        padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
        background: 0 0.1em no-repeat;
        background-size: 1em 1em;
    }
</style>
```

And finally, `Folder.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import File from './File.svelte';

    export let expanded = false;
    export let name;
    export let files;

    function toggle() {
        expanded = !expanded;
    }
</script>

<span class:expanded on:click={toggle}>{name}</span>

{#if expanded}
    <ul>
        {#each files as file}
            <li>
                {#if file.files}
                    <svelte:self {...file}/>
                {:else}
                    <File {...file}/>
                {/if}
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
{/if}

<style>
    span {
        padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
        background: url(/tutorial/icons/folder.svg) 0 0.1em no-repeat;
        background-size: 1em 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .expanded {
        background-image: url(/tutorial/icons/folder-open.svg);
    }

    ul {
        padding: 0.2em 0 0 0.5em;
        margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
        list-style: none;
        border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    }

    li {
        padding: 0.2em 0;
    }
</style>
```